# Relation between two equations (upper bound)

Tags: algorithm, relation, upperbound

I have an algorithm that has the following cost:

```
C(Alg) <= t * Z
```

I've found on the web an exercise that state the following :

```
if t>=x,     I can say that     C(Alg) <= x * Z  <= t * Z
```

but it looks strange.. do you agree?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [math.se].

Comment: Consider x=0 and t=1. One doesn't have to think very much to see that what you're asking is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in general not true. Think about the case where $Z$ is negative, then this does not hold true:

```
$$\text{if} x \leq Z, \text{then} xZ \leq tZ$$
```

Comment: oh i'm sorry.. i didn't say that Z is always positive

Comment: Even if Z is always positive, the conclusion that `C(Alg)<=x*Z<=t*Z` under the condition that `x<=t` is incorrect because `xZ` is a tighter upper bound.